# A hosted wiki with support for code snippets (and syntax colouring)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, wiki, code-snippets

Can anyone point me in the direction of a hosted wiki with decent support for syntax highlighting of code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to find a specific hosted wiki with "decent support for syntax highlighting of code" ... and can only find a hosted wiki ... you can always embed code from http://pastebin.com/

> In order to embed this content into your website or blog, simply copy and paste one of the codes provided below.
>
> Pastebin will take care of hosting and formatting.
> We currently offer two ways for you to embed:

1. JavaScript Embedding (shows full code, full height depending on amount of lines in paste)
   `<script src="http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=##########"></script>`
2. Iframe Embedding (you can set the frame height by adding the CSS value 'height:100px;' for example)
   `<iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=##########" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>`

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question, but a good solution anyway so I'm marking it as answered.